# Proof by induction of the formula for $2^0+2^1+2^2+...+2^n$?

Tags: proof-verification, summation, induction, geometric-progressions

$2^0+2^1+2^2+...+2^n$ for $n ∈ \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$.

I made a conjecture that this is $2^{n+1} - 1$. Now I have to prove it by induction.

---

I tested the base case where it's equal to zero, and it worked.

Then I did "assume $k∈ \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$ and $2^0+2^1+2^2+...+2^k$". I got marked down for saying "Let $n=k+1$", and did a bunch of math for it to become $2^{k+2} -1$ and I was apparently wrong >_>?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How do I prove 2^0+2^1+2^2+...+2^n for n ∈ N∪{0} = 2^(n+1) -1

I mean, I wrote exactly what that link says and I got marked down. Is there a way to post a picture of what I wrote?

Comment: http://imgur.com/mI2SkbF
Here's a link to my homework and what I got wrong. I really can't figure it out.

Comment: @Test The marking goes for the wording chosen. You should have left out the "Let $n=k$" and "Let $n=k+1$". The rest is okay.

Comment: @Test You assumed what you were trying to prove in the first line after "Let $n=k+1$."  If you had left off the quantity on the RHS of the equals sign in that centered line, you would have gotten full (or nearly full) credit.

Comment: @AlexR Um...  Are you sure?  (I want to make sure I'm reading it right.)

Comment: @anorton At least I would have accepted that. The computations are correct and if you write "Let $k\in \mathbb N_0$ and $\sum_{i=0}^k 2^i = 2^{k+1}$. Then (...) $\Rightarrow \sum_{i=0}^{k+1} 2^i = 2^{k+2} - 1$." It's fine to me.

Comment: @AlexR Ok.  I see.

Comment: @Test Your corrector probably wants you to learn how to write accurate proofs, or he had a really bad day.

Comment: He demands very accurate proofs. but he gave me 25% credit. he said that "Let n=k+1" is WRONG under the guidelines of "Incorrect assumption", and then said that I have to derive 2^(k=1) -1 case from here. So I don't really know what to correct or what to do.

Comment: I'll second what apnorton said. Disregarding the incorrect use of the word "let", for the $n=k+1$ case, the first thing you wrote was that it *equaled* $2^{k+2}-1$. That's wrong! You can't just *say* it equals that, you must show it. While you continued to demonstrate this, the damage was done. It's a step that is not logically in order.

Answer (score 0):

You have to prove it on both sides, but you can make the assumption that you prove it for earlier cases.

So to prove for $n+1$ you may assume it holds for $n$.

Comment: I know, but what was the mistake I made? I set assume it's true for n=k, and try to prove it for k+1, which I did, but I got it wrong. here's a pic of my homework:  http://www.imgur.com/mI2SkbF

Comment: I think your proof is correct though unclear and the corrector may have misunderstood, or is deducting points for unclarity.
The 'Let' stuff is unclear because we're not doing assignments. Symbol rewrite is also not necessary and unclear.
If instead of writing 'Let n = k + 1' you'd say, Let's calculate for n + 1, and not already put what you need to prove on RHS, it would be OK.